# C# Nullable: Make nullchecking dependent on another property/variable

Tags: c#, null, attributes, nullable

I have just enabled null checking in my .net core 3.1 project.

The problem is that I have a response class

```
public class DecryptResponse
{
    public DecryptStatus Status { get; set; }

    //This is the attribute in question
    [NotNullWhen(Status==DecryptStatus.Ok)]
    public Stream? Stream { get; set; }

    public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public enum DecryptStatus
{
    Ok,
    InvalidData,
    KeyChecksumFailure,
    NoData,
    UnhandledError
}
```

The above is used in this situation where the `Verify` method does not allow nulls.

But I know that the stream is not null since `DecryptStatus==Ok`

```
if (decryptResponse.Status != DecryptStatus.Ok)
    return (decryptResponse, null);

var verifyResponse = Verify(customerId, decryptResponse.Stream);
return (decryptResponse, verifyResponse);
```

Are there any tags that allows for this logic or does it need a major rewrite of the code?

Comment: `NotNullWhen` works only with method parameters, with property you can use `NotNull` attirbute. Or convert it to method and use something `NotNullIfNotNull`. You can find some ideas in this article [Try out Nullable Reference Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/)

Answer (score 24):

#### For .NET 5 and later: Use the new `MemberNotNullWhen` attribute.

- [The `MemberNotNullWhenAttribute` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullwhenattribute) was introduced in .NET 5.0 and C# 9.0.

  - <sub>(C# 9.0 also introduced `init` properties, which are useful for *optional* properties in immutable types without needing extraneous constructor parameters).</sub>
- Use `MemberNotNullWhen` by applying it to any `Boolean`/`bool` property where its `true`/`false` value asserts that certain fields and properties will be "`notnull`" when that property is `true` or `false` (though you cannot yet directly assert that a property *will be `null`* based on a property)
- When a single `bool` property indicates multiple properties are `null` or `notnull` then you can apply multiple `[MemberNotNullWhen]` attributes - or you can use the `params String[]` attribute ctor.
- You might notice that your `Status` property is not `bool` - which means you will need to add a new property that adapts the `Status` property to a `bool` value for use with `[MemberNotNullWhen]`.

...like so:

```cs
public class DecryptResponse
{
    public DecryptStatus Status { get; init; }

    [MemberNotNullWhen( returnValue: true , nameof(DecryptResponse.Stream))]
    [MemberNotNullWhen( returnValue: false, nameof(DecryptResponse.ErrorMessage))]
    private Boolean StatusIsOK => this.Status == DecryptStatus.Ok;

    public Stream? Stream { get; init; }

    public string? ErrorMessage { get; init; }
}
```

Of course there's a huge gaping hole with this approach: there's no way for the compiler to verify that `Status`, `Stream`, and `ErrorMessage` are set correctly. There is nothing stopping your program from doing `return new DecryptResponse();` without setting *any* properties. That means the object is in an invalid state.

You might think that's not a problem, but if you need to keep on adding or removing new properties to a class eventually you'll get careless and forget to set a required property you need and then your program explodes.

A better implementation of `DecryptResponse` would use two separate constructors for the 2 mutually-exclusive valid states, like so:

```cs
public class DecryptResponse
{
    public DecryptResponse( Stream stream )
    {
        this.Status = DecryptStatus.OK;
        this.Stream = stream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        this.ErrorMessage = null;
    }

    public DecryptResponse( DecryptStatus error, String errorMessage )
    {
        if( error == DecryptStatus.OK ) throw new ArgumentException( paramName: nameof(error), message: "Value cannot be 'OK'." );
        
        this.Status       = error;
        this.Stream       = null;
        this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(errorMessage ));
    }

    public DecryptStatus Status { get; }

    [MemberNotNullWhen( returnValue: true , nameof(DecryptResponse.Stream))]
    [MemberNotNullWhen( returnValue: false, nameof(DecryptResponse.ErrorMessage))]
    private Boolean StatusIsOK => this.Status == DecryptStatus.Ok;

    public Stream? Stream { get; }

    public String? ErrorMessage { get; }
}
```

And then used like so:

```
DecryptResponse response = Decrypt( ... );
if( response.StatusIsOK )
{
    DoSomethingWithStream( response.Stream ); // OK! The compiler "knows" that `response.Stream` is not `null` here.
}
else
{
     ShowErrorMessage( response.ErrorMessage ); // ditto
}
```

---

### Long-answer (for writing better classes *in general*):

The alternative to updating to .NET 5 + C# 9, and to avoid the *invalid state* problems described above is to use a better class design which **[makes invalid states unrepresentable](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/)**.

I'm not a fan of mutable *result objects* (aka *in-process DTOs*) - i.e. those with `get; set;` on every property) because without a *primary-constructor* there's no way to have hard assurances that an object instance will be initialized correctly.

(This is not to be confused with web-service DTOs, especially JSON DTOs, where there can be good reasons for making every property mutable, but that's another discussion)

If I were writing for an older .NET platform where `MemberNotNullWhen` isn't available, then I'd design `DecryptResponse` like below:

```cs
public abstract class DecryptResponse
{
    public static implicit operator DecryptResponse( Stream okStream )
    {
        return new DecryptResponse.OK( okStream );
    }

    public static implicit operator DecryptResponse( ( DecryptStatus status, String errorMessage ) pair )
    {
        return new DecryptResponse.Failed( pair.status, pair.errorMessage );
    }

    private DecryptResponse( DecryptStatus status )
    {
        this.Status = status;
    }

    public DecryptStatus Status { get; }

    public sealed class OK : DecryptResponse
    {
        public OK( Stream stream )
            : base( DecryptStatus.OK )
        {
            this.Stream = stream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        }

        public Stream Stream { get; }
    }

    public sealed class Failed : DecryptResponse
    {
        public Failed ( DecryptStatus status, String errorMessage )
            : base( status )
        {
            if( status == DecryptStatus.OK ) throw new ArgumentException( message: "Value cannot be " + nameof(DecryptStatus.OK) + "." );
            this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(errorMessage));
        }

        public String ErrorMessage { get; }
    }
}
```

(From a CS-theoretical perspective, [the above class is a *union type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type)).

The advantages of this design are numerous:

- The class design makes it clear there's only 2 possible "shapes" of the result data: "OK" or "Failed" - and each subclass owns its context-specific data members (`Stream` and `ErrorMessage` respectively).
- The type heirarchy is closed (the base `abstract` type has a `private` constructor) and its two child types are both `sealed`, making it impossible for there to be a result other than `OK` or `Failed`.

  - This is basically the same as an "enumerated (class) type", like Java's `enum`-classes. Whereas C# a `enum` is more like a named constant and the compiler and language provides no guarantees that a C# `enum` value is valid at runtime (e.g. you can always do `MyEnum v = (MyEnum)123` even when `123` is not a defined value).
- Validation logic in the `OK` and `Failed` constructors provide a guarantee that `DecryptStatus.OK` *always* means the result type is `DecryptResponse.OK`  with a non-`null` `Stream` property. Similarly, if `Status != DecryptStatus.OK` you have a `DecryptResponse.Failed` object instead.
- The `implicit` operator definitions mean that methods that return a `DecryptResponse` can directly return a `Stream` or `ValueTuple<DecryptStatus,String>` and the C# compiler will automagically perform the conversion for you.

Such a result-type is returned like so:

```
public DecryptResponse DecryptSomething()
{
    Stream someStream = ... // do stuff
    if( itWorked )
    {
        return someStream; // Returning a `Stream` invokes the DecryptResponse conversion operator method.
    }
    else
    {
        DecryptStatus errorStatus = ...
        return ( errorStatus, "someErrorMessage" ); // ditto for `ValueTuple<DecryptStatus,String>`
    }
}
```

or if you want to be explicit:

```
public DecryptResponse DecryptSomething()
{
    Stream someStream = ... // do stuff
    if( itWorked )
    {
        return new DecryptResponse.OK( someStream );
    }
    else
    {
        DecryptStatus errorStatus = ...
        return new DecryptResponse.Failed( errorStatus, "someErrorMessage" );
    }
}
```

And consumed like so:

```
DecryptResponse response = DecryptSomething();
if( response is DecryptResponse.OK ok )
{
    using( ok.Stream )
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
else if( response is DecryptResponse.Failed fail )
{
    Console.WriteLine( fail.ErrorMessage );
}
else throw new InvalidOperationException("This will never happen.");
```

(Unfortunately the C# compiler is not yet smart enough to recognize closed-type hierarchies, hence the need for the `else throw new...` statement, [but hopefully eventually that won't be necessary](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113)).

If you need support for serialization with JSON.net then you don't need to do anything, as JSON.NET supports serialization of these types just fine - but if you need to deserialize them then then you'll need a custom contract resolver, unfortunately - but writing a general-purpose contract-resolver for closed-types is straightforward and once you've written one you won't need to write another.

Comment: Your `StatusIsOK` is private, how do you access it outside the class?

Comment: @huang By not using that version and using the `DecryptResponse.OK` class below it instead.

Comment: Is it possible only depends on the Enum? Without additional bool check.

Comment: @huang No, because C#s nullable analysis (and `NotNullWhen`/`MaybeNullWhen` attribute types) only support flow-analysis on `const bool`  values, not enum types: it's a limitation we have no control over. I agree it's an annoying limitation, though.

Answer (score 1):

[`NotNullWhenAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=netcore-3.1) is for usage with parameters only. It tells the compiler that (out) parameter is not null when the method returned specified value (true or false). E.g.

```
public bool TryParse(string s, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Person person);
```

It means that `person` will not be null when method returned `true`.

But this attribute is not suitable for your what you trying to achieve:

- NotNullWhen cannot be applied to class properties - it can be used only with method parameters.
- NotNullWhen does not provide dependency on some external value (like class property) - it can only use the return value of the method parameter belongs to. And even more, this return value can be only boolean.

But you can try to use method instead

```
public bool TryDecrypt(Foo bar,
    [NotNullWhen(false) out DecryptError error, // wraps error status & message
    [NotNullWhen(true)] out Stream stream)
```

Or use null-forgiving operator

```
if (decryptResponse.Status == DecryptStatus.Ok)
{
    // decryptResponse.Stream!
}
```